# Geronimo with MySQL - Can't deploy .ear (DeploymentException: Unable to resolve resource reference)

Tags: mysql, datasource, geronimo

I have a web app attempting to connect to MySQL 5.5.11.  However, when I try to depoly my .ear file to Geronimo 2.2.1 the following exception is thrown:

org.apache.geronimo.common.DeploymentException: Unable to resolve resource reference 'jdbc/MyDataSource' (Could not auto-map to resource.  Try adding a resource-ref mapping to your Geronimo deployment plan.

**Here's I what I've done:**

- I created a database pool name jdbc/MySQL with the Geronimo console (Using the Geronimo database pool wizard).  In the wizard, I choose MySQL Connector/J 3.0.17.  I verified the jar was downloaded to {GERONIMO_HOME}/repository.  I verified that I could create a table and insert data using that database pool in the Geronimo console.
- I add the following to my WEB-INF/web.xml file:

> ```
>   <resource-ref>
>     <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyDataSource</res-ref-name>
>     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
>     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
>     <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
>   </resource-ref>
> ```

- I add the following to my WEB-INF/geronimo-web.xml:

> ```
> <dep:environment>
>     ...
>
>     <dep:dependencies>
>         <dep:dependency>
>             <dep:groupId>console.dbpool</dep:groupId>
>             <dep:artifactId>jdbc_MySQL</dep:artifactId>
>         </dep:dependency>
>     </dep:dependencies>
> </dep:environment>
>
> <name:resource-ref>
>     <name:ref-name>jdbc/MyDataSource</name:ref-name>
>     <name:resource-link>jdbc/MySQL</name:resource-link>
> </name:resource-ref>
> ```

What can I be doing wrong?  How do I properly connect my web app to MySQL and deploy to Geronimo?

**Here's what I'm working with:**

- Geronimo 2.2.1 with Tomcat 6
- MySQL 5.5.11
- Eclipse Indigo Release
- Mac OS X 10.6.7

Thanks